# Codeigniter 2.1 - join one to many

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have to tables:

**gallery** -> **id_gallery, name, desc, data**

and:

**images** -> **gallery_id, name**

One gallery can have many images. I need to select all galleries and all images and on view page present all galleries and all images which contains that gallery. How can do this?

I have code like this for now:

```
$this->db->select('*')->from('image')->join('gallery','id_gallery = gallery_id');
$q = $this->db->get();
return $q = $q->result_array();
```

EDIT:

```
<?php foreach ($gallery as $gal):  ?>
<figure>
<a href="<?php echo IMG ?>galerija/<?php echo $gal['name'] ?>/<?php echo $gal['path'] ?>" rel="galerija[slike]" class="figure_img">
<img src="<?php echo IMG ?>galerija/<?php echo $gal['naziv'] ?>/thumbs/<?php echo $gal['path'] ?>" >
<figcaption><?php echo $gal['name']; ?></figcaption>
</a>
</figure>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This foreach loop is producing 5 div tags instead of one (if gallery have 5 images for example).

Comment: You need to reference the tables in the join? `gallery.gallery_id = image.id_gallery`

Comment: I did that, it makes no difference. At the moment situation is following: if gallery have 5 images it creates 5 **div** tags, and it needs to create only one.

Comment: Well that's an issue with your loop construct not the sql!

Comment: Sasha try my answer and let me know.........

Comment: @Dale I have edited question. Any recommendation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to select all the images from images table for all galleries..........

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('images');
$this->db->join('gallery', 'gallery.id_gallery = images.gallery_id');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $q = $query->result_array();
```

or in the other way. Write a model function and in that

```
public function get_images()

 {
    $res=$this->db->query("select * from images and gallery where gallery.id_gallery = images.gallery_id");
    if($res->num_rows()>0){
        return $res->result("array");
    }

    return array();

}
```

Comment: I did this, and it is working, but I still have slitter problem. I will edit the question.

Comment: If, for example, gallery have 5 images, it will produce 5 div tags, and I need only one, in which I will show all the images for that gallery,

Comment: then do one thing after u got the result in model file in array. Pass that to view file and in between div tags write a loop to display all the images in that gallery....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20177/discussion-between-venkat-and-sasha)